# Is there a way to stream data into a blob (or generate a giant blob)

Tags: javascript, html

Checking MDN I see there used to be [`BlobBuilder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BlobBuilder) and that I could call [`blobBuilder.append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BlobBuilder#append()) to continue adding data to a blob but according to MDN `BlobBuilder` is deprecated in favor of the [`Blob` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob). Unfortunately the `Blob` constructor requires all data in memory at construction time. My data is too large to be in memory at construction time. Looking at the [`File` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) see nothing there either.

Is there a way to generate large data client side and put it in a blob? For example say I wanted to render a 16k by 16k image. Uncompressed that's a 1gig image.

I have an algorithm that can generate it 1 or a few scan lines at a time but I need way to write those scan lines into a file/blob and then when finished I can use the standard way to let the user download that blob but, I can't seem to find an API that let's me stream data into a blob.

The only thing I can think of is apparently I can make a `Blob` from `Blob`s so I suppose I can write each part of the image to a separate blob and then send all the blobs to another blob to get a big blob.

Is that the only solution? Seems kind of um .... strange. Though if it works then ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

---

Someone voted to close as they don't understand the question. Here's another explanation.

Write 4 gig to a blob

```
 const arrays = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < 4096; ++i) {
   arrays.push(new Uint8Array(1024 * 1024)); // 1 meg
 }
 // arrays now holds 4 gig of data
 const blob = new Blob(arrays);
```

The code above will crash because the browser will kill the page for using too much memory. Using `BlobBuilder` I could have done something like

```
 const builder = new BlobBuilder();
 for (let i = 0; i < 4096; ++i) {
   const data = new Uint8Array(1024 * 1024); // 1 meg
   builder.append(data);
 }
 const blob = builder.getBlob(...);
```

That would not have run out of memory because there is never more than 1meg of data around. The browser can flush the data being appended to the `BlobBuilder` out to disk.

What's the new way to achieve writing 4 gig to a blob? Is it only writing lots of small blobs and then using those to generate a larger one or is there some more traditional way where traditional means steaming into some object/file/blob/storage.

Comment: That's pretty much how you would do it, you can also append lots of say `Uint8Array`, in your case might make more sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appending Blob data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970729/appending-blob-data)

Comment: Thanks but it's not actually a dupe. The answer on that other question actually shows what I'm trying to avoid as it's answer. It says "append to an array" but appending to an array will run out of memory.

Comment: I have retracted by close vote.

Comment: See also [StreamSaver.js](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know, the data that the blob will contain must be ready to pass to the constructor. Let us take the example from MDN:

```
var aFileParts = ['<a id="a"><b id="b">hey!</b></a>'];
var oMyBlob = new Blob(aFileParts, {type : 'text/html'});
```

Now, we have two options:

1. We can append data to the array, and then convert it to a blob:

   ```
   var aFileParts = ['<a id="a"><b id="b">hey!</b></a>'];
   aFileParts.push('<p>How are you?</p>');
   var oMyBlob = new Blob(aFileParts, {type : 'text/html'});
   ```
2. Alternatively, we can use blobs to create the blob:

   ```
   var oMyOtherBlob = new Blob([], {type: 'text/html'});
   oMyOtherBlob = new Blob([oMyOtherBlob, '<a id="a"><b id="b">hey!</b></a>'], {type : 'text/html'});
   oMyOtherBlob= new Blob([oMyOtherBlob, '<p>How are you?</p>'], {type : 'text/html'});
   ```

You may build your own `BlobBuilder` encapsulating that... given that appending to an array seems to lead you to run out of memory, let us encapsulate the second option:

```
var MyBlobBuilder = function() {
     var blob = new Blob([], {type: 'text/html'});
     this.append = function(src)
     {
         blob = new Blob([blob, src], {type: 'text/html'});
     };
     this.getBlob = function()
     {
         return blob;
     }
};
```

Note: tested with your code (replaced `BlobBuilder` with `MyBlobBuilder`), did not run out of memory on my machine. Windows 10, Chrome 67, 8 GB Ram, Intel Core I3 - 64 bits.