# What are maximum dimensions of Three.js render canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, webgl

When I set render canvas size to ~4000x4000px it's ok, however starting from around 4000 (tested 5k, 6k, 8k) it seems that scene is "cut off" in some way. See image below:

[image]

So up to ~4k content is properly rendered in the center of canvas and for higher canvas sizes it cuts the content.

1. Is it a Three.js/WebGL limitation?
2. If yes then what are actual maximum canvas dimensions that don't cause any "deformations"?
3. Is there anything I can do about it? I need to get canvas snapshot in high resolution (8k).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a limitation of `three.js` but a limitation of the maximum size of the drawing buffer. It's defined by the browser vendor and can't be exceeded by an application. More information in this github issue:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5194

Answer (score 4):

> Is there anything I can do about it? I need to get canvas snapshot in high resolution (8k).

You can render portions of the scene using [`Camera.setViewOffset`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.setViewOffset) and then assemble the parts into a large image. You can look at [this sample](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_multiple_canvases_grid.html) where it renders the image in 4 separate parts. In that example it makes 4 renderers but for your case you'd only need one and just `render->capture canvas->render->capture canvas-> repeat until you get all parts`. Then you need a way to stitch those parts together. You could use gIMP or Photoshop for example.

Here's library that does this

https://greggman.github.io/dekapng/

I know there is an answer here I wrote that shows how to do this in three.js since I wrote that library because of my answer. Unfortunately 10 minutes of searching didn't bring up >:(

Comment: This is awesome!

Comment: @gman is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51245334/13778439) your answer?

Comment: Here's [another library](https://github.com/taseenb/THREE.Highres) specifically for three.js