# Render and save 300dpi image

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I was trying to edit this beautiful Rutt-Etra demo code https://www.airtightinteractive.com/2011/06/rutt-etra-izer/
My issue is that i need to render and save pictures of the highest resolution possible (300dpi would be great, 600dpi even better). Totally new to three.js whatsoever, just looking to know at which part of the code should i care for/look at.
Any help is appreciated (even alternative methods to get the biggest resolution with this image processing)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53518155/what-are-maximum-dimensions-of-three-js-render-canvas/ and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53534876/128511)

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?